# Threading optimization. Running many commands on a list of files

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, subprocess

I have a script that has to run on many files. In each file there are the execution of external commands that generate different files or I need to operate in the same file however in different folders.

I would have something like this:

```
Proc1_File1 -> Proc2.1_File1 -> Proc2.2_File1 -> Proc3.File1 -> Proc4.File1
Proc1_File2 -> Proc2.1_File2 -> Proc2.2_File2 -> Proc3.File2 -> Proc4.File2
Proc1_FileN -> Proc2.1_File2 -> Proc2.2_FileN -> Proc3.FileN -> Proc4.FileN
```

So I would have in this example a total of **5** processes, however for example `Proc2.1` and `Proc2.2` can run at the same time.

Also I would need to restrict the number of processes that run at the same time, mainly for the `Proc2.2` and `Proc3.3` because the external commands are very memory intensive, so running more than 4-5 processes at same time may result in very low memory.

Sorry for this question being so generic, but I don't know where to start and how to solve this problem. As if I have to run every process sequentially it would be too much time consuming.

So, I think that I may need to use a queue. I have been limiting the execution of the external commands using a list and wait like for example here:

```
__list_commands.append(Popen(__command, shell=True, cwd=str(__p.parent)))
exit_codes = [p.wait() for p in __list_commands]
```

It would be part of a function that runs the first process. However this makes to wait that a command end to run the next, so it makes sequentially, and I would like to run each process in parallel, and run sequentially each process, first proc1, then proc2...

Thank you and sorry for this so generic question.

Answer (score 0):

not sure that you need a process.. but just in case have a look here:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor

or maybe you simply need threads?
https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor

keep in mind that if you spawn 3 threads they will run in the same CPU, and if their task is computationally intensive they will each use 33% of that CPU.